# new badge: good timing

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

I would like to suggest a new badge.

In one of [the golfs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66285/product-over-exclusive-and-inclusive-ranges/66288#66288) Morgan Thrapp and i posted an answer the exact same second. He said that should be a badge and i think hes right.

The rules for the badge should be to post an answer with someone within a certain timeframe, i would say 3 seconds.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 19):

The purpose of (most) badges is to encourage a certain behaviour that is deemed good on SE. (There are a few exceptions, like Tumbleweed, and I'm pretty sure they'd go if the badge system was redesigned from scratch today.) I'm not exactly sure what good behaviour your badge idea would encourage.

Comment: i thought badges were also a bit for fun and this was supposed to be a fun badge. If its only to encourage good behaviour this badge obviously doesnt make sense.

Comment: @Eumel The hats from winter bash are more for fun than badges, but even there adding hats that encourage really odd behaviour are what gives the winter bash a bad name sometimes.

Comment: @Eumel I should probably clarify that. Of course, the badges are supposed to be fun, or else we wouldn't be trying to get them. But my point is, whether that's the intention or not they *do* encourage certain behaviour, because people will want to get that badge. So when someone suggests adding a badge, my first thought is "what would people do if they saw they can get a badge for it". Of course, they'd co-ordinate with someone else and sync their answers to get the badge. [ctd.]

Comment: a) I don't see how that can possibly increase the quality of the content on the site. b) If the badge can be obtained multiple times it would devalue all other badges, because it's really cheap to obtain.